# Replace token in a xml file based on pattern using maven plugin

Tags: regex, maven, replace, token

I've a maven project which has a xml property file(prop.xml).That xml file contains some fully qualified file path like

```
<test:loc>file:\C:\test\data\testData.xsl</test:loc>
<test:loc>file:\C:\test\data\devData.xsl</test:loc>
<test:loc>file:\C:\test\data\qa\qa.xsl</test:loc>
```

..........
and so on

Now I require to replace the '\' with the forward slash('/') based on ,,.xsl file type(and anything else if requires) patterns so that the replacements taken place in these type of location.

Expected output:

```
<test:loc>file:/C:/test/data/testData.xsl</test:loc>
<test:loc>file:/C:/test/data/devData.xsl</test:loc>
<test:loc>file:/C:/test/data/qa/qa.xsl</test:loc>
```

.....
and so on

How can I perform this  using any maven plugin (e.g. maven-replacer-plugin) so that I can include it in the pom file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest transforming the XML file by applying an XSLT stylesheet using the [XML maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/).

Comment: This is fine but is it possible to perform this using maven-replacer-plugin.If so could you please show me the way.